# How to create Devise extension?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need to create reusable Devise extension. This is my first experience of creating gems. So, according sources of other Devise extensions, i've started with creating file **devise_sms_authenticatable.rb** in **'lib'** folder with following code:

```
# encoding: utf-8
unless defined?(Devise)
  require 'devise'
end

Devise.add_module :sms_authenticatable, :model => 'devise_sms_authenticatable/model'
```

Also, i've created folder **devise_sms_authenticatable** in the **'lib'** folder, and added **model.rb** with code:

```
# encoding: utf-8
module Devise
  module Models
    module SmsAuthenticatable
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

After all i've added my new extension to the **User** model.

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  devise ..., :sms_authenticatable
end
```

But application falls with error `uninitialized constant Devise::Models::SmsAuthenticatable (NameError)`. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Would you mind posting links to the source of other Devise extensions that you reference in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're putting the SmsAuthenticatable module already on `Devise::Models`, there is no need to add it through `add_module`, though you may need to require it on `config/initializers/devise` (if you're writing a gem, you may avoid this, since you will not touch devise.rb on initializers).

You can also write its code without Devise::Models in your gem lib directory and only add this line

```
Devise.add_module :sms_authenticatable, :model => 'sms_authenticatable'
```

And Devise should add the module.

Comment: Great! Added **require 'devise_sms_authenticatable'** in **devise.rb**, and everything works! So, it's only needed until i'll put it all into a separated gem?